# Ubuntu 16.04 VM Guest - Boot on TTY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, nvidia-graphics-card

On my VM guest Ubuntu 16.04 (host Win10), X server seems to fail start. The tricky thing is that installation + 1st reboot are OK, it's only on the next ones that I always fallback on TTY and console prompt. Furthermore, while arriving to login prompt, screen seems to flicker.

`startx` command fails with "connection refused". I saw several posts with similar problems, especially with nvdia cards (mine GTX 960M), but so far, I troed to reinstall both "Nouveau" and nvidia-current for proprietary drivers, without success.

Anyone got a lead to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall nvidia-current  (`sudo apt remove nvidia-current`) and use only the default open source graphics drivers.
2. Increase VirtualBox video RAM to the maximum amount of 256MB. From the Windows command line run:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox"
   vboxmanage modifyvm "Name of virtual machine" --vram 256
   ```

   If you run VirtualBox and go to *Display* in the Settings window, you would see:

   [image]
3. Optionally uncheck *Enable 3D Acceleration* and *Enable 2D Video Acceleration*.

Comment: THanks for this reply. I did try your solution (remove nvidia-current, increase video memory), unfortunatly, it didn't solve the problem... Would you see why? Also, could you edit your post to remove "MB." because AFAIS in help, vram param expects a number only.

Comment: I sort of fixed the problem by reinstalling previous LTS 14.04 Trusty Thar. No graphics display problem so far, but a bit desappointing

Comment: Next time you have a boot problem don't use `startx` because it causes more problems than it solves. Instead press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to show the console, login with your username and password from the console, and run the command `sudo service lightdm start` to display your normal login screen.